# Certificates and provisioning profiles

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am looking for a more thorough guide on what the different steps of code signing an application. I have read the guide which is available in the provisioning portal, but I do not grasp the concept of certificates and provisioning profiles and the difference between developer and distribution.

In XCode there are also different schemes (using XCode 4). I do not understand the purpose of it. I have successfully uploaded an application to AppStore so I do not need a guide on how to do it. What I am searching for is links to a more detailed "text" where I can read about this, or if anyone wants to explain it for me it will be much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Everything is easy - certificate is that thing that allows you to produce digital signature over data, binding your developer identity to your application (i.e. ensuring 'developer John' created this application).
Provisioning profile binds developer to devices - i.e. it claims 'Developer John can upload apps to device iPhone1,iPhone2,iPhone3'.

Comment: So if I was just distributing an app, I don't need to change the provisioning profile?

Comment: @NickolayOlshevsky : Venkat means that if only wants to distribute his app on app store, and dont want to install on any device himself then in that case he dont have to add different device udid in provisioning profile

Comment: @VenkatS.Rao : Yes in that case you don't need to change the provisioning profile.

Comment: Once you've made changes for your devices...do you have to undo something to be able to publish to AppStore?