# Signing Certificates and Provisioning Profile for iOS Development

Tags: ios

I'm new to iOS development and I'm getting a bit confused with the usage of signing certificate and provisioning profile. Let's say there's an iOS project which involves multiple developers and each developer works on the development using their own MacBook. In this case, do all the developers need to use the same signing certificate and provisioning profile for the app? As I'm aware that the private key of the certificate is stored in the Keychain of the developer who created the CSR. Can multiple certificates tie to the same provisioning profile? Any clarification would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284846/certificates-and-provisioning-profiles

Comment: If you are comfortable sharing the private key from keychain, I would recommend sharing the private key, certificate and provisioning profile with all the developers